# Traveling conveniences in Maui

Tags: hawaii

I'm traveling to Maui and I wanted to inquire about how difficult it is travel in Maui if it will take a while to travel from place to place.

I am going to go there and would like to stay in hotel that will allow me easy access to both snorkeling and hiking the 7 sacred pools. Hence, I don't want to end up on the other side of town and not be able to see the attractions just because of travel time.

Comment: There are several towns on the island of Maui.  Which are you planning to stay in?

Comment: Well, that's part of my dilemma. I'm not quite sure where to stay. I'd like to ideally stay in a place that's equidistant to good snorkeling and hiking. My research tells me the resort on South Maui is pretty good. But not sure

Comment: The seven sacred pools are *way* out on the east side of the island. There's literally nothing else out there, certainly not any resorts. The east coast of Maui is very rugged and it would be dangerous to snorkel out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you best bet is to stay in or about Kahului.  Being the principal population center of the island, you will find getting to multiple places will be easiest from there.

If by 'resort on South Maui' you mean the Wailea area, that's even worse because you can't get to Haleakalā National Park without backtracking to Kahului.

Finally, if you're not renting a vehicle, all bus routes center on Kahului.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to stay close to the 7 Sacred pools is Travasa near Hana (the only hotel in Hana), on the East side of the island, which is in the middle of nowhere. Good snorkeling is really on the south or west sides of the island about 2.5 hours drive away. Yes, Hana it is only about 45 miles away from Kahului (the major central city), but the road has 45 one lane bridges on it where you have to wait for traffic. Average speed tops out at 25 miles per hour.

The best place to stay is in the Wailea area, also known as Kihei; that is one of the largest resort areas of the island. Kahului only has two very small hotels which are not great. Yes, Kahului is the central hub for business, but you don't want to stay there, it isn't pretty. Kihei has tons of condos to rent and Beautiful resorts.

7 sacred pools is about a 2.75 hour drive from Kihei or Wailea.

You are wanting to do activities that are unfortunately on completely different sides of the island.

Also, the bus system is inadequate on Maui. Not set up for travelers, basically for the working public. No bus goes to Hana unless it is a tour bus, which may be a good option for you.